# Laravel Live Search How to add the join table of role id tables to users table?

Tags: laravel

No Search

| ID | Role Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | John Doe |
| 2 | User | Jay |

When I search the ID the role name is not appearing

| ID | Role Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | John Doe |
| 2 |  | Jay |

Live Search Query function

```
public function usearch(Request $request) {
        $output="";

        $users = User::
        where('id','Like','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('name','Like','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('username','Like','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->get();
        
        foreach($users as $users)
        {
            $output.=
            '<tr>
            <td class="bg-gray-100 px-4 font-mono text-center"> '.$users->id.' </td>
            <td class="bg-gray-100 px-4 font-mono text-center"> '.$users->role_name.' </td>
            <td class="bg-gray-100 px-4 font-mono text-center"> '.$users->name.' </td>
            <td class="bg-gray-100 px-4 font-mono text-center"> '.$users->username.' </td>
            <td class="bg-gray-100 px-4 font-mono text-center"> '.$users->created_at.' </td>
            <td class="bg-gray-100 px-4 font-mono text-center"> '.$users->updated_at.' </td>
            <td class="bg-gray-100 px-4 font-mono flex">              
            '.'<a href="/admin/users/'.$users->id.'/edit"
            class="text-orange-400 px-6 py-2 rounded-xl">
            '.'Edit
            </a>
            '.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
        return response($output);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this:

```
foreach($users as $users)
```

To this:

```
foreach($users as $user)
```

and update the code inside the foreach to use $user instead of $users.

Check if that solves your problem

Comment: its not gonna worth i need to join table it but when do the join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id') the live search is not working

Comment: `DB::table('users')->leftJoin('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')->leftJoin('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')->get();`

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause